# Sagepay 2.23 to 3.00. Need to update to AES

Tags: c#, asp.net, opayo

The following code is part of our checkout payment page that registers the payment with the sagepay server. I just need to change the encoding before the post and decoding after the get response to conform to the AES requirement.

Am I right in thinking that my strPost needs breaking up to non encrypted part and the Crypt part?
In which case I have some work to do.

```
//** The full transaction registration POST has now been built **
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding objUTFEncode = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    Uri objUri = new Uri(SagePay.SystemURL(SagePay.ConnectTo, "purchase"));

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest objHttpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(objUri.ToString());
    objHttpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    objHttpRequest.Method = "POST";

    objHttpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] arrRequest = objUTFEncode.GetBytes(strPost);
    objHttpRequest.ContentLength = arrRequest.Length;

    Stream objStreamReq = objHttpRequest.GetRequestStream();
    objStreamReq.Write(arrRequest, 0, arrRequest.Length);
    objStreamReq.Close();

    //Get response
    HttpWebResponse objHttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objHttpRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader objStreamRes = new StreamReader(objHttpResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

    strResponse = objStreamRes.ReadToEnd();
    objStreamRes.Close();

    //** No transport level errors, so the message got the SagePay **
    //** Analyse the response from VSP Direct to check that everything is okay **
    //** Registration results come back in the Status and StatusDetail fields **
    strStatus = SagePay.FindField("Status", strResponse);
    strStatusDetail = SagePay.FindField("StatusDetail", strResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you Rik.I have worked out that my server implementation does not require the AES part. I'm running over https so no need to encrypt further. Looks like a simple protocol value change is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The AES requirement only applies to using the Form integration method. Looks like you are posting to Sage Pay's Direct API. So you may not have much to do at all :-)